# Neural network; having problem with model result

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running NN to predict industrial production of countries.

My data is as following: (producing it by R)

```
structure(list( Word1 = c("0", "0", "0"), Word2 = c("15", "15",  "13"), Word3 = c("1", "1", "1"), Word4 = c("0", "0", "0"), Word5 = c("0", "0", "0"), IndustrialP = c(107.35586
, NA_real_, 113.66342
)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I split the data as following:

```
y=df.IndustrialP
X=df.drop('IndustrialP', axis=1)
split = int(len(df)*0.8)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:split], X[split:], y[:split], y[split:]
```

codes for model as following:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(5,)),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=20, epochs=50)
```

Unfortunatelly, I am getting `loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00` for all iterations

What would be the problem here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The labels in your df have missing values that need to imputed first:

```
df = df.fillna(df.mean()['IndustrialP'])
```

Moreover, this is a regression problem that requires another loss function such as MSE or MAE.

```
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="sgd")
```

Comment: Thanks but I run both of the codes that you wrote above, I am still getting `loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00`

Answer (score 0):

This is the whole colde after saving the csv file from R:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('nn.csv')
df = df.fillna(df.mean()['IndustrialP'])
df.head()

    Word1   Word2   Word3   Word4   Word5   IndustrialP
0   0   15  1   0   0   107.35586
1   0   15  1   0   0   110.50964
2   0   13  1   0   0   113.66342

y=df.IndustrialP
X=df.drop('IndustrialP', axis=1)
split = int(len(df)*0.8)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:split], X[split:], y[:split], y[split:]

import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(5,)),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
])
model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="sgd")
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=20, epochs=50)
```

Epoch 1/50
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 11810.6562

Comment: Your code worked well thank you! Can I ask one more thing: In addition to loss, I want to see the accuracy too. So I added `metrics=['accuracy'])` inside the compile. I run that code as following: `model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="sgd",metrics=['accuracy'])` It again gave me `loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00` I did not get its reason.

Comment: I am not sure about the accuracy, but it usually comes up while having a classification problem since, in machine learning, it measures the percentage of predicting certain classes correctly. In contrast, in a regression, you could have a near prediction to the actual value, but it's gonna affect the accuracy because it is not the same value.